# How do I capture different scopes using the bound library?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use Edward's `bound` library to model the graph of levels in my game - at least levels as they are stored representationally, before being realised as OpenGL objects.

A level consists of a bunch of vertices, whereby we can form a wall between pairs of vertices. Vertices are also used to create simple polygons - sectors (rooms). A sector owns walls, but also has some material properties. There is a lot of sharing going on between vertices, walls, sectors and materials, so to exploit the graph-like nature of this, I turned to the `bound` library.

The code so far is,

```
-- Vertices live alone and aren't influenced by anything else. Perhaps these
-- should still be a functor, but act like Const?
data Vertex = Vertex
  { vertexPos :: V2 CFloat }

-- Textures also live alone, and are simply a wrapper around the path to the 
-- texture.
data Texture = Texture
  { texturePath :: FilePath }

-- A Material needs to refer to one (or more) textures.
data Material a = Material
  { materialDiffuseTexture :: a
  , materialNormalMap :: Maybe a
  }

-- A Sector needs to refer to materials *and* vertices. How do I reference two
-- types of variables?
data Sector a = Sector
  { sectorFloorMaterial :: a
  , sectorWallMaterial :: a
  , sectorCeilingMaterial :: a
  , sectorVertices :: Vector a -- How do we guarantee these aren't material ids?
  , sectorFloorLevel :: Double
  , sectorCeilingLevel :: Double
  }

-- A wall points to the sectors on either side of the wall, but also its start
-- and end vertices. The same problem with 'Sector' appears here too.
data Wall a = Wall
  { wallFront :: a -- This should be a sector
  , wallBack :: Maybe a -- This should also be a sector
  , wallV1 :: a -- But this is a vertex
  , wallV2 :: a -- This is also a vertex
  }

-- Level ties this all together, with the various expressions making up the
-- vertices, the walls between them, the sectors, and the materials.
data Level = Level
  { levelVertices :: IntMap.IntMap Vertex
  , levelSectors :: Vector (Scope Int Sector ())
  , levelWalls :: Vector (Scope Int Wall ())
  , levelMaterials :: Vector (Scope Int Material ())
  , levelTextures :: Vector (Scope Int Texture ())
  }
```

However, I'm not sure if I'm putting the pieces together properly here. For example, I have `Sector a`, where I am using `a` to identify both vertices and materials. However, it's important that I use the right identifier in the right place!

I'd love to hear feedback on whether or not I'm going in the right direction by modelling this somewhat constrained AST via `bound`.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to have materials and vertices referenced by the same attribute of `Sector`?

Comment: @bheklilr Well, if we have `Sector a`, then we would have `Sector { floorMaterial :: a, vertices :: Vector a }` - because both the floorMaterial and list of vertices should point to other data in the scene.

Comment: @bheklilr i've updated the code listening to hopefully make things a little clearer.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need the parametrization in the first place?  Your `Material` data type could just be `Material = Material { materialDiffuseTexture :: NonEmpty Texture, materialNormalMap :: Maybe (NonEmpty Texture) }` using [semigroups](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.15.3/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html), I presume you were instead doing `Material Texture` or `Material [Texture]`.

Comment: Or maybe I'm just misunderstanding here because I'm not familiar enough with what you're trying to do, but it seems like a lot of parametrization when you seem to know exactly what needs to go there.

Comment: I'll admit that there is a bit of "wanting to know how @edward-kmett thinks" :) However, I've seen this with a lot of DSLs - there are often multiple scopes that overlap, and I'm not sure how to best work with them.

Comment: If we could all think like Kmett, then hackage would probably need a few more servers to handle all the uploads.  I'll take a look at this problem a bit more and check out the source for `bound` to see if I can come up with anything, but I can't make any guarantees of success.

Comment: I'm not sure that `bound` is really a good fit for this problem.  Why not create `newtype MaterialId = MaterialId Int` and `newtype VertexId = VertexId Int` and use those monomorphic types within `Sector`, `Wall`, etc?  The you just need an environment with two `IntMap`s, one for each type of id, to get the sharing you want?

Comment: Indeed, Kmett himself said "ah, you want higher-order bound. that doesn't exist". So I don't think I can do this with bound. What you propose is exactly what I started with, so I'll probably have to go back to that.